# Xcode is not recognizing FUITableViewDataSource

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to use FUITableViewDataSource as my tableView datasource but I keep getting "unrecognized filetype" errors.

this is my head of file.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import SwiftyJSON
```

and Podfile has:

```
pod 'FirebaseCore', '~> 3.0'
pod 'FirebaseDatabase', '~> 3.0'
pod 'FirebaseUI', '~> 3.0'
```

and bit of my code that is not working:

```
var dataSource: FUITableViewDataSource!
```

Amy I doing something wrong here?

SOLUTION: actually you have to import FirebaseDatabaseUI

Comment: maybe import FirebaseUI?

Comment: It says there is not such module FirebaseUI

Answer (score 0):

The code below is how the code should be implemented. You need to provide more of your code as we need to see how you implemented the dataSource. Also, what do you mean by the code is not working. Is it showing any error messages?

```
let firebaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
var dataSource: FUITableViewDataSource!

self.dataSource = self.tableView.bind(to: self.firebaseRef) { tableView, indexPath, snapshot in

// Dequeue cell

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)

/* populate cell */

return cell
}
```

Comment: It says undelared type 'FUITableViewDataSource'